# Sliding menu issue

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer, sliding

I have created a sliding menu.. it worked perfect, but today I wanted to add a new block.. i did it, it was perfect, but after the creation, it appeared an error which said to add a superwarning to `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` ...i solved the error, but till then the app was not working anymore, and the app crashes when i had to open the sliding activity..

Here is my logcat:

```
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orar.cngcnasaud.MainActivity.getActionBar
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.orar.cngcnasaud.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-22 13:39:12.989: E/AndroidRuntime(485):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And if I understood properly, I would think that the problem is at the onCreate option with the 2 codes I wrote bellow.. so, here's my onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        _initMenu();
        mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer);
        mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    }
```

Thanks a lot !

The errors in the logcat have changed:

LOGCAT:

```
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3769)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.orar.cngcnasaud.NsMenuAdapter.getView(NsMenuAdapter.java:108)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:714)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-22 12:42:58.730: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what class are you extending?

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

Comment: NsMenuAdapter line 108 - which/what is that?

Comment: show `NsMenuAdapter.java:108`

Comment: holder.textHolder.setText(item.title); ..this is the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActionBar()` is available only since SDK 11. So, looks like you are using the older SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If your android:minSdkVersion is set to 8 (API-8), it does not provide getActionBar() (only since API-11).

If lint warnings are suppressed, you won't get a compile time error for that.

Try http://actionbarsherlock.com/ - backward compatibility helps.

If you want to check, 
see if this works:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

The updated logcat shows there is an error in identifying your resource id.

See if you have the `TextView` (in question) in the same layout which is passed to the adapter. Or check its initialization.

Comment: Still not working even i setted as you said and change  the API min level from 8 to 17.. as it was before, but still not working..still crashing

Comment: now you have a different error, the getActionBar() problem was solved

Comment: @Ezekiel You need to provide the full answer for this please.

Comment: Look at the post which I checked as the answer. I have changed the apk and it worked.